# Prototyping a function - C++

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

Lately, some of my CPP tutorials have used *function prototypes* . I understand you must initialize the function, but what is the overall use of it? Couldn't you use just as well write the entire function before main() instead of defining a prototype?

```
int returnValue(void);

int main()
{
  std::cout << returnValue() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

int returnValue(void)
{
  return 10;
}
```

Comment: If you have many functions calling one another, you would have an interesting task arranging them in the precise order that a callee is always defined before the caller. And of course, you could have two or more functions calling each other recursively. Besides, you wouldn't normally write the whole program in a single source file, once the program becomes large enough. Then you would put prototypes into headers, and implementations into several source files.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: Ahh, now that makes logical sense. Now in terms of quick/short programs, they don't really matter?

Comment: @EnthusedBinary Yes, for your sample it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: They do matter. Good code organization is important from the get-go

Comment: One more thing, sorry for the neediness, would I put my prototypes in my custom headers when used? Insertion into the header instead of written before main() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important usage case is when you separate your implementation from the declarations. In other words, you declare your functions/classes etc in a header file, and define (i.e. implement) them in cpp files. In this way, you can distribute your program with the implementation fully compiled in a shared or static library. In order to use a pre-compiled function you need to introduce it to your program via a declaration. Example:

**a.h**

```
void f();
```

**a.cpp**

```
void f(){/* implementation here */}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Including `"a.h"` in `main()` is declaring the function. Once you compile the `a.cpp` once, you don't need it's source any more, the program will run provided you have at least access to the object file, but in order for the linker to find the function `f()` you need to declare it.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now and will begin using for cleaner execution and greater organiztion

Answer (score 2):

> Couldn't you use just as well write the entire function before main() instead of defining a prototype?

I can think of the following cases where you cannot.

**Functions used in multiple files**

If a function is used in multiple source (.cpp) files, you can define the function only in one source file. You have to declare it in the remaining source files. For convenience and to avoid errors, such declarations are put in header files. The header files are then `#include`d by the source files.

**Mutually recursive functions**

If `foo` calls `bar` and `bar` calls `foo`, you cannot implement them without providing a declaration of at least one of the functions.

As a matter of good practice, it's better to declare both functions first. Then you can implement them in any order.

Answer (score 0):

If one doesn’t specify the function prototype, the behavior is specific to C standard (either C90 or C99) that the compilers implement. Up to C90 standard, C compilers assumed the return type of the omitted function prototype as int. And this assumption at compiler side may lead to unspecified program behavior.

Later C99 standard specified that compilers can no longer assume return type as int. Therefore, C99 became more restrict in type checking of function prototype. But to make C99 standard backward compatible, in practice, compilers throw the warning saying that the return type is assumed as int. But they go ahead with compilation. Thus, it becomes the responsibility of programmers to make sure that the assumed function prototype and the actual function type matches.

To avoid all this implementation specifics of C standards, it is best to have function prototype.